# Uncaught Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'Users.ji8A7TkSldfdvieDqGxko9eV3Jy1.gender'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was watching 10. Firebase Web Tutorial 2019 - Adding Data to Firebase Database - Account Settings Tutorial 09 on YouTube I followed every step as he did but this didn't work out any help?

```
// Checking t0 update info
$("#btn-update").click(function(){
  var fName = $("#fname").val();
    var sName = $("#sname").val();
    var uName = $("#uname").val();
    var country = $("#country").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var gender = $("#gender").val();
    
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Users");
    var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var usersRef = rootRef.child(userID);
    
    if(fName != "" && sName != "" && uName != "" && country != "" && phone != "" && gender != ""){
        var userData = {
            "firstName": fName,
            "secoundName": sName,
            "userName": uName,
            "country": country,
            "phone": phone,
            "gender": gender,
        };
        
        usersRef.set(userData, function(){
            if(error){
                 var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMassage = error.message;

        console.log(errorCode);
        onsole.log(errorMassage);
  
        window.alert("Message : " + errorMassage);
        
            }else{
        window.location.href="post.html";   
            }
        });
    }else{
        window.alert("Form is incomplete.! Please fill out all field.");
    }
});
```

Comment: You should share some error messages here so people can help you out. Exactly what is it that didn't work?

Comment: The Error was "Uncaught Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'Users.ji8A7TkSldfdvieDqGxko9eV3Jy1.gender' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'll reply based on your comment: "The Error was "Uncaught Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'Users.ji8A7TkSldfdvieDqGxko9eV3Jy1.gender' "

This error occurs because firebase won't accept any values as "undefined". In your case you are getting undefined in "gender" field. You should validate somehow your data before submitting it to firebase. For instance you could do this:

```
var userData = {
    "firstName": fName||'',
    "secoundName": sName||'',
    "userName": uName||'',
    "country": country||'',
    "phone": phone||'',
    "gender": gender||'',
};
```

Or you could validate your data some other way before submitting it.